# Quando removemos um elemento utilizando HTMLSelectElement.remove() os eventos atribuídos ao elemento são removidos também?

Tags: javascript, html

Quando removemos um elemento utilizando `HTMLSelectElement.remove()` os eventos atribuídos a ele são deletados por completo também?

[MDN - remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove)
[W3Schools - remove](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_remove.asp)

Devo utilizar o `removeEventListener` antes de remover o elemento?

**Exemplo:**

```js
let sel = document.getElementById("existingList");

function fc_click () {

  console.log ('Clique')

}

sel.addEventListener ('click', fc_click);

console.log (sel.click);

sel.remove();

// TENTA RESGATAR O ELEMENTO NOVAMENTE
sel = document.getElementById("existingList");

console.log (sel.click);
```

```html
<select id="existingList" name="existingList">
  <option value="1">Option: Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option: Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option: Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A função `remove` não deleta o elemento, ela apenas remove ele do nó ao qual o elemento está apensado. Por exemplo, se você mantiver uma referência ao elemento, você pode apensá-lo a um outro nó ele vai acompanhado do evento. Por outro lado, caso você não vá usar o elemento em outro lugar, você só deve remover o evento caso você não queira que ele seja disparado e somente eventos muito específicos são disparados quando o elemento não está apensado ao DOM (onload, onabort, onerror, etc.), no demais, o Garbage Collector se encarrega de deletar o elemento e os eventos associados a ele.

Comment: @v.Santos certo, então o elemento apensado será removido pois não existira mais referencia a ele em meus scripts, com isso os eventos tipo `click` será removido sem utilizar `removeEventListener`, correto? Se não tenho que utilizar `removeEventListener` antes de deletar o mesmo... a questão e tentar ganhar memoria mesmo sendo uma pequena parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema dos eventos adicionados por `addEventListener()` é que nunca esteve muito claro onde e como eles são armazenados. Existe uma discussão a esse respeito e o fato de não ser possível acessar todos os eventos anexados a um elemento sempre me pareceu algo problemático. A esse respeito, recomendo a ótima discussão na stack overflow em inglês:

[get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046741/get-event-listeners-attached-to-node-using-addeventlistener)

Considerando isso e que no que diz respeito a sua pergunta, no geral, eu mantenho o que eu disse no comentário, isto é, a eliminação de objetos da memória é de responsabilidade do Garbage Collector, e, por essa razão, só é necessário remover o evento caso exista a possibilidade de ele ser disparado e você não queira que isso aconteça. Desse modo, em eventos como 'click', a remoção me parece desnecessária.

Contudo, em circunstâncias específicas, sobretudo, se você precisar criar e remover um número muito grande de elementos com eventos associados a ele, talvez, seja importante realizar a remoção do evento antes do elemento ser removido. Digo isso com base no seguinte exemplo:

```
/*<< AVISO: ESSE SCRIPT FOI CRIADO UNICAMENTE PARA A REALIZAÇÃO DE UM TESTE. 
ESSE SCRIPT GASTA UMA QUANTIDADE MASSIVA DE MEMÓRIA RAM E PODE TRAVAR O NAVEGADOR  >> */

function teste(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        const callback = () => alert("Hi!");
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.addEventListener('click', callback);
        //div.removeEventListener(click, callback);
        div.remove();
    }
}
setInterval(teste, 100);
```

No script acima, a função `teste()` cria um elemento, apensa ao DOM, associa a um evento e depois remove o elemento criado do DOM. Isso um milhão de vezes por segundo. Quando o trecho `div.removeEventListener(click, callback);` não está sendo executado ocorre vazamento de memória. Na realidade, executado nos principais browsers, o script precisou de menos de 20 segundos para acabar com os 8GB de RAM do meu computador.

Por outro lado, executado a remoção do evento, isto é, tirando as duas barras de comentário de `div.removeEventListener(click, callback);` não houve vazamento de memória. Sendo, portanto, em circunstâncias semelhantes, altamente recomendável a remoção do evento.